# Series expansion in Infinity issue with Zeta(s) function

Tags: special-functions, series-expansion

With this code:

```
Series[Zeta[s], {s, Infinity, #}] & /@ Range[10] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Series  expansion for the `Zeta(s)` function around `x = Infinity`,works fine.
But with this:

```
Series[4^s (Zeta[s] - 1 - 2^-s - 3^-s), {s, Infinity, #}] & /@ Range[10] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

very strange behavior occurs. **Is this normal behavior?**

Comment: Looks like a bug. What if you use `Expand[]` on the expression within `Series[]`?

Comment: @J.M. Yes, with `Expand[]` works fine. The strange behavior occurs with MMA 10.4.1 ?. I have MMA 10.2.0.

Comment: Yes, it's the same in 10.4.1.

Comment: Since [`O`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/O.html) only supports polynomials, `Series` does not return an error term (i.e. `SeriesData`) for `Zeta[s]` at `Infinity`. Since it returns a `Normal` expression instead, it simply subtracts with your `1 + 2^-s + 3^-s`, giving `0`. See the second to last example in the Possible Issues section [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Series.html).